# Python - replace few characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

i trying to understand that.

I must delete few characters in my string loaded from .txt

```
f = open("my_file.txt")

myList = [".", ",", "-"]
removed = ""

for i in myList:
    removed += f.read().replace(f'{i}', '')

print(removed)
```

My solution working only on one char, why?

Comment: The first time `f.read()` is executed, the seek will be pointing to the end of the file

Comment: Move `f.read()` to outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

`f.read()` will change the seek position. Hence, you need to store the file contents in a variable

```
f = open("my_file.txt")

myList = [".", ",", "-"]
f_data = f.read()

for i in myList:
    f_data = f_data.replace(f'{i}', '')

print(f_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
myList = [".", ",", "-"]

with open("my_file.txt") as f:
    f_data = f.read()
    for i in myList:
        f_data = f_data.replace(f'{i}', '')
print(f_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you the following code:

```
import re
removed = ""
pattern = re.compile(r'[\.,-]')
with open('your_file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        removed += pattern.sub('',line)

print(removed)
```

If it is not mandatory to iterate over `myList` you could use a regular expression.